# C# DataGridView UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm new in C# and my data grid view user control is not working.

I created User Control and in user control I have DataGridView Control I set the Data Source and all formatting in user control. Later on my main form when I need to display this control I click on button and change this user control visible property to true. issue is i'm not see any data in data grid. Any idea what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

**Edit:**

```
System.Data.DbManager Dbmgr = new DbManager("System.Data.OleDb", conn);
DataTable dataTable = Dbmgr.Retrieve(sql);
dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```

And then later i put this control into my main Form and set Visible property to false and then when user click the button I set this:

```
dataFilesDetails.Visible = true; dataFilesDetails.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: in User control Load method I have this code

Comment: System.Data.DbManager Dbmgr = new DbManager("System.Data.OleDb", conn);
            DataTable dataTable = Dbmgr.Retrieve(sql);        

          

            dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;

and then later i put this control into my main Form and set Visible property to false and then when user click the button I set this.

 dataFilesDetails.Visible = true;
                dataFilesDetails.BringToFront();

Comment: Can you edit your question with your code when you create and call your usercontrole ?